# XSLT stylesheet detects table elements but doesn't show them

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I want to output the names, domain and usage of a database where its version is equal to 20i. I have created a stylesheet that does this - when I load my xml, it detects that I have an element matching my requirements in the table, but doesn't actually show them. No idea what I'm doing wrong!

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xrt.xsl"?>
        <Inventory>
          <DatabaseName>
            <GlobalName>Tom</GlobalName>
            <Function>production</Function>
            <Domain>tom.info</Domain>
             <Administrator EmailAlias="xrichards" Extension="221">Xavier Richards</Administrator>
             <Attributes Type="Production" Version="20ix"/>
             <Comments>
             ...
             </Comments>
             <Usage>
             500
             </Usage>
             </DatabaseName>

             <DatabaseName>
            <GlobalName>Ricardo</GlobalName>
            <Function>production</Function>
            <Domain>tom.info</Domain>
             <Administrator EmailAlias="xrichards" Extension="221">Xavier Richards</Administrator>
             <Attributes Type="Production" Version="20i"/>
             <Comments>
             ...
             </Comments>
             <Usage>
             500
             </Usage>
             </DatabaseName>

             <WebserverName>
                <GlobalName>Jim</GlobalName>
                <Function>distribution</Function>
                <Domain>jim1235.com</Domain>
                 <Administrator EmailAlias="rkarvani" Extension="134237">Richard Karvani</Administrator>
                 <Administrator EmailAlias="stones" Extension="222237">Steve Jones</Administrator>
                 <Attributes Type="Production" Version="20i"/>
                 <Comments>
                 ...
                 </Comments>
                 <Usage>
                 1200
                 </Usage>
               </WebserverName>
             </Inventory>
```

XSLT Document:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
               <xsl:template match="/">
                  <html>
                     <body>
                        <h1>My Server List</h1>
                        <h2>Database Servers</h2>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Inventory/DatabaseName" />
                        <h2>Webservers</h2>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Inventory/WebserverName" />
                     </body>
                  </html>
               </xsl:template>

               <xsl:template match="DatabaseName">

                <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Domain</th>
                    <th>Usage</th>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select="Attributes[@Version='20i']">
                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="GlobalName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Domain"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Usage"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
               </xsl:template>



               <xsl:template match="WebserverName">
                    <table border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Domain</th>
                    <th>Usage</th>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select="Attributes[@Version='20i']">
                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="GlobalName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Domain"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Usage"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
               </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put the condition about that version into the `apply-templates` and move the `table` creation to the another template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
               <xsl:template match="/">
                  <html>
                     <body>
                        <h1>My Server List</h1>
                        <h2>Database Servers</h2>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Domain</th>
                                <th>Usage</th>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Inventory/DatabaseName[Attributes[@Version='20i']]" />
                        </table>
                        <h2>Webservers</h2>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Domain</th>
                                <th>Usage</th>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Inventory/WebserverName[Attributes[@Version='20i']]" />
                        </table>
                     </body>
                  </html>
               </xsl:template>

               <xsl:template match="DatabaseName">                

                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="GlobalName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Domain"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Usage"/></td>
                  </tr>

               </xsl:template>



               <xsl:template match="WebserverName">

                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="GlobalName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Domain"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Usage"/></td>
                  </tr>

               </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! That all works - one thing though, my stylesheet is creating two tables for the databases instead of one? EG, I'm pretty sure my code should create a Name, Domain and Usage table headers and then underneath that the values that match my conditions all as part of one table. At the moment, it's creating a table for the first result it finds and then another table for the second result and so on. How do I put it all matching results as part of one table? (Hope this makes sense!)

Comment: You need to move the code creating the `table` element outside of the template matching `DatabaseName`.

Comment: That gives me a parsing error - does it have to be in its own template?

Comment: @neX, yes, you have to move it to another template higher in the hierarchy, I have edited the sample to show the simplest approach by putting it into the template for the `/` document node which already exists.

Comment: @ Martin Honnnen, thanks very much - really helpful!